# Best practice for exit code to use for custom signal handler?

Tags: c, linux, signals

I want to add some clean up to the SIGTERM signal. At the same time I have code checking process return code and possible signal exits. Now I have doubts on best practice for signal handling. Which is it?

```
void handle_sigterm(int sig) 
{ 
    /* cleaning up some stuff */
    /* … */
    /* but what exit code to use? */

    /* maybe 0, because the handler promises more graceful termination than default SIGTERM */
    _exit(0); 

    /* exit code as-if exited by SIGTERM, because that is what initiated termination */
    _exit(128+sig);

    /* similar to above, but leave the details for the default handler */
    signal(SIGTERM, SIG_DFL); /* (not entirely sure this is needed) */
    raise(SIGTERM);
}
```

Comment: If the signal can be re-raised during the processing or your handler, you might want to put `signal(sig, SIG_DFL);` at the top of your function. Otherwise your signal handler might call your signal handler, which is probably something you want to avoid. Or block processing of further signal until this one is done.

Comment: @AugustinLopez The default for `sigaction` is the currently handled signal is blocked for the duration of the handler. You'd need `sa.sa_flags&SA_NODEFER` to change that.

Comment: @PSkocik I'm beginning to think the function should be invoked directly instead of the detour through `raise()`, e.g. `signal(sig, SIG_DFL); signal(sig, SIG_DFL)(sig)`. Signal blocking and such should no longer apply.

Comment: @Andreas `signal(sig, SIG_DFL); signal(sig, SIG_DFL)(sig);` is equivalent to `signal(sig,SIG_DFL); (SIG_DFL)(sig);` but `SIG_DFL` usually isn't a valid `void (*)(int)`. Linux has `#define SIG_ERR  ((void (*)(int))-1)
#define SIG_DFL  ((void (*)(int)) 0)
#define SIG_IGN  ((void (*)(int)) 1)
`. It should be clear from that `SIG_DFL` isn't callable.

Comment: @PSkocik Ohhh I just assumed `signal(sig, SIG_DFL)` sets the signal handler *to the function pointer of the sig default handler*, as opposed to `raise(sig)` checking for invalid function pointers (SIG_DFL, SIG_IGN) before invokation.

Comment: @Andreas The default handlers are handled purely in the kernel space (at least on Linux). They can't be (at least a purely) user-mode functions because they need to cause process deaths or stops accompanied with special wait statuses (as returning by wait/waitpid/waitid). AFAIK, there's no user-level API for generating such wait statuses other than by having the child process literally die or be stopped by the appropriate signal.

Answer (score 3):

The `_exit(0)` option is wrong; it indicates success.  Using `_exit(EXIT_FAILURE);` might be OK. Dying by reraising the signal allows the parent process to determine unambiguously that the process dies because of the signal.  The `128 + SIGTERM` convention is used by POSIX (the shell reports the exit status of a process that died as a result of a signal by setting `$?` to 128 plus the signal number), but it is mildly ambiguous because a process can exit voluntarily with that status, as shown by your code possibly doing so.

If your program is normally invoked by the shell, then any of the non-zero exits is OK, but either of the "128 plus signal number" variants is better.  If your program is normally invoked by another process of your own that can usefully distinguish between “definitively died from signal” and “probably died from a signal”, the "reraise the signal" option is probably best, though it is not often used in practice.